# About getting rs id from chromosome and position

Tags: r, variants

Hi I have a dataset with chromosome and position.

```
VARIANT_ID   chromosome position
17_26797415_147499  17  26797415
17_26797556_147500  17  26797556
```

How can I assign rs id using R? This data have more than 500 SNPs.

---

- Update: [BioMart](https://www.ensembl.org/info/data/biomart/index.html) was used as suggested by @RamRS
- 'NA NOT FOUND' was a resulting error.
- @RamRS recommended inputing `na.omit` in the input vector
- This appear to have resolved the situation

Comment: You may want to explore reutils or biomaRt. See this thread on biostars: https://www.biostars.org/p/323319/

Comment: Thank you. I tried, but I got a strange error message .
Query ERROR: caught BioMart::Exception::Usage: Filter NA NOT FOUND

Comment: That's not strange - one your inputs is NA. Wrap the input vector with `na.omit` and you should not see the error.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it.